# Creating matrix from random block rows of another matrix without loop (in R)?

Tags: r, random, matrix, block, rows

I am trying to create a matrix by drawing random block rows from another matrix. I have managed to do so with a loop.

```
set.seed(1)
a_matrix  <- matrix(1:10,10,5) # the matrix with original sample 

b_matrix <- matrix(NA,10, 5) # a matrix to store the bootstrap sample 

S2<- seq(from =1 , to = 10, by =2) #[1] 1 3 5 7 9

m <- 2 # block size of m 

for (r in S2){  start_point<-sample(1:(nrow(a_matrix)-1), 1, replace=T) 
                #randomly choose a number 1 to length of a_matrix -1  
                b_block <- a_matrix[start_point:(start_point+(m-1)), 1:ncol(a_matrix)] 
                # randomly select blocks  from matrix a 
                b_matrix[r,]<-as.matrix((b_block)[1,]) 
                b_matrix[(r+1),]<-as.matrix((b_block)[2,]) # put the blocks into matrix b 
} 
b_matrix
#we now have a b_matrix that is made of random blocks (size m=2)
#of the original a_matrix
```

The loop method works but it is clearly not very efficient and it is not possible to extend it to other block size (for e.g. having a blocksize of 3)  .What is a cleaner and expandable approach ? Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is more in-line with [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I tried to clean it up a bit and generalize the use of `m`:

```
random_block_sample <- function(a_matrix, m = 2L) {
   N <- nrow(a_matrix)
   stopifnot(m <= N)
   n <- ceiling(N / m)
   s <- sample(N - m + 1L, n, TRUE) # start_point
   i <- unlist(lapply(s, seq, length.out = m))
   b_matrix <- a_matrix[i, , drop = FALSE]
   head(b_matrix, N)
}

set.seed(1L)
random_block_sample(a_matrix, m = 2L)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]    3    3    3    3    3
#  [2,]    4    4    4    4    4
#  [3,]    4    4    4    4    4
#  [4,]    5    5    5    5    5
#  [5,]    6    6    6    6    6
#  [6,]    7    7    7    7    7
#  [7,]    9    9    9    9    9
#  [8,]   10   10   10   10   10
#  [9,]    2    2    2    2    2
# [10,]    3    3    3    3    3

set.seed(1L)
random_block_sample(a_matrix, m = 5L)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]    2    2    2    2    2
#  [2,]    3    3    3    3    3
#  [3,]    4    4    4    4    4
#  [4,]    5    5    5    5    5
#  [5,]    6    6    6    6    6
#  [6,]    3    3    3    3    3
#  [7,]    4    4    4    4    4
#  [8,]    5    5    5    5    5
#  [9,]    6    6    6    6    6
# [10,]    7    7    7    7    7
```